# how to drag and drop on dropped position and delete item from dragview in android

Tags: android

MainActvity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnDragListener {
    private ListView mListView;
    private LinearLayout mFrameLayout;
    private List<ItemModel> mList = new ArrayList<>();
    private DraggingAdapter mDraggingAdapter;

    View.OnLongClickListener dragListener = new View.OnLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
            ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");
            View.DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(view);
            view.startDrag(data, shadowBuilder, view, 0);
            return true;
        }
    };

    View.OnTouchListener touchListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
            Log.e("TouchListener Up", "X: " + view.getX() + ", Y: " + view.getY());
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                Log.e("TouchListener Down", "X: " + view.getX() + ", Y: " + view.getY());
                return true;
            } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mListView = findViewById(R.id.listview);
        mFrameLayout = findViewById(R.id.framelayout);
        mDraggingAdapter = new DraggingAdapter(touchListener);
        for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
            mList.add(new ItemModel(false, i));
        }
        //mListView.setOnDragListener(this);
        mFrameLayout.setOnDragListener(this);
        mListView.setAdapter(mDraggingAdapter);
        mDraggingAdapter.setData(mList);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
                // Do nothing
                Log.e("onDrag", "DragEvent.Action_drag_started");
                break;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
                //v.setBackground(enterShape);
                Log.e("onDrag", "DragEvent.Action_drag_entered");
                break;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
                //v.setBackground(normalShape);
                Log.e("onDrag", "DragEvent.Action_drag_Exited");
                break;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION:
                //Log.e("onDrag Location", "X: " + v.getX() + ", Y: " + v.getY());
                break;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
                Log.e("onDrag", "DragEvent.Action_drag_dropped");
                // view dropped, reassign the view to the new ViewGroup
                float xCoordinates = v.getX();
                float yCoordinates = v.getY();

                View view = (View) event.getLocalState();
                Log.e("ACTION_DROP", "X: " + view.getX() + ", Y: " + view.getY());
                ItemModel model = (ItemModel) view.getTag();
                //DraggingAdapter owner = (DraggingAdapter) view.getParent();
                //mList.remove((int) view.getTag());
                LinearLayout container = (LinearLayout) v;
                View viewCloning = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this).inflate(R.layout
                        .item_view, null);
                //viewCloning.setX(xCoordinates-(viewCloning.getWidth()/2));
                //viewCloning.setY(yCoordinates-(viewCloning.getHeight()/2));

                ((AppCompatTextView) viewCloning.findViewById(R.id.textview)).setText("Textview " +
                        model.itemText);
                if (!model.isDragged) {
                    model.isDragged = true;
                    mDraggingAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    viewCloning.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.grey_background);
                    Log.e("Cloned View", "" + viewCloning.getWidth() + " " + viewCloning.getHeight());
                    int width = new Random().nextInt((container.getWidth() - viewCloning.getWidth()));
                    int height = new Random().nextInt((container.getHeight() - viewCloning
                            .getHeight()));
                    Log.e("Params Values: ", "Width: " + width + "  Height: " + height);
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(view.getWidth(),
                            view.getHeight());
                    viewCloning.setId(model.itemText);
                    viewCloning.setLayoutParams(params);
                    //viewCloning.setLayoutParams(positionParams);

                    //mDraggingAdapter.remove(mDraggingAdapter.getItem((int) view.getTag()));
                    //mDraggingAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    //((ViewGroup)view.getParent().getParent()).removeView((ViewGroup)view.getParent());
                    viewCloning.setTag(model);
                    //viewCloning.setOnLongClickListener(dragListener);
                    //viewCloning.setOnTouchListener(touchListener);
                    container.addView(viewCloning);
                    view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
                break;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
                Log.e("onDrag", "DragEvent.Action_drag_Ended");
                Log.e("DragListener Up", "X: " + v.getX() + ", Y: " + v.getY());
                //v.setBackground(normalShape);
            default:
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

DraggedAdapter:

```
public class DraggingAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private List<ItemModel> data = new ArrayList<>();
    private View.OnTouchListener touchListener;

    public DraggingAdapter(View.OnTouchListener listener) {
        touchListener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return data.size() > 0 ? data.size() : 0;
    }

    @Override
    public ItemModel getItem(int position) {
        return data.size() == 0 ? new ItemModel(false, 0) : data.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = null;
        if (view == null) {
            view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_view, parent,
                    false);
        }
        ItemModel item = getItem(position);
        ((AppCompatTextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textview)).setText("Textview " + item.itemText);
        if (!item.isDragged) {
            view.setOnLongClickListener(longClickListener);
            //view.setOnTouchListener(touchListener);
        }
        view.setBackgroundResource(item.isDragged ? R.drawable.selected_background : R.drawable.grey_background);
        view.setTag(item);
        return view;
    }

    View.OnDragListener onDragListener = new View.OnDragListener()

    {
        @Override
        public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
            return false;
        }
    };

    View.OnLongClickListener longClickListener = new View.OnLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
            ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");
            View.DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(view);
            view.startDrag(data, shadowBuilder, view, 0);
            //view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            return true;
        }
    };

    View.OnTouchListener dragListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            // start move on a touch event
            if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");
                View.DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(view);
                view.startDrag(data, shadowBuilder, view, 0);
                //view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                return true;
            }
            return false;

        }
    };

    public void setData(List<ItemModel> data) {
        this.data = data;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    tools:context="com.example.techjini.draganddrop.MainActivity">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" android:fillViewport="true"
        android:layout_weight="0.6">

        <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
            android:id="@+id/framelayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </ScrollView>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.3"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:dividerHeight="10dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

This is my code using this code i am able to drag and drop from list-view  item to dragdview which is Linaerlayout inside scroll view but when i  drag from list-view item to drag view then each time it set top left corner  while i am trying to  to drag   list-view item to to same position where i will drop it should not move to top left and  also i want to delete item from dragged view i dont know how to delete item from drag view please suggest how  to achievable this thanx

Comment: Just follow this simple [solution](https://medium.com/@ipaulpro/drag-and-swipe-with-recyclerview-b9456d2b1aaf)

Comment: @Wizard i dont have to swipe i have to drag item to another view and in listview that item will still exist

Comment: Check this https://medium.com/@ipaulpro/drag-and-swipe-with-recyclerview-b9456d2b1aaf

Comment: @Wizard no help from this i check and tried my given code i am able to drag in another view but i want to drag same which position where i end drag that i am not able to do

Comment: Just to be clear, You want to drag `row_item` of `ListView` to `LinearLayout` and arrange them vertically. Correct?

Comment: No vertically i want listview item to that position  of linear layout or any other layout where we end drop currently when we drop any place it goes vertically that i dont want i want where ever i keep it should place on that place @Wizard

Comment: This is sort of interesting stuff. Don't you think you should put it on github? so that developers can fork it and make it work?

Comment: if u want link of code i can give u can u  please confirm

Comment: @Wizard just tell suggest me  please how to remove item from drag and drop view in android

Comment: which library you are using for DragView?

Comment: no libray i have use OnDragListener  i have use if u want sample i can give u i am able to drag item in dragview but not able to delete item in dragview can u send email adress will send u sample i just need help to delete item  from dragview