# how to keep center relativelayout inside DragLayer in android

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

```
   <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:layout_weight=".1"
            android:background="@color/colorPaleGrey2"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingTop="20dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/meeting_text"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="Entrepreneur Meet Up"
                    android:textColor="@color/blackDark"

                    android:textSize="20.1sp"
                    android:textStyle="normal" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/time"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/meeting_text"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:lineSpacingExtra="6sp"
                    android:text="(11:30AM - 4:00PM)"
                    android:textColor="@color/bluey_grey_three"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:textStyle="normal" />

            </RelativeLayout>

            <com.kdcos.contsync.utilities.dragview.DragLayer
                android:id="@+id/framelayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/rl_dropView"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:padding="40dp">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imageView"
                        android:layout_width="30dp"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:background="@drawable/ic_drop_cards" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView2"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center"
                        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:lineSpacingExtra="10sp"
                        android:text="Drop Cards Here"
                        android:textColor="@color/blackDark"
                        android:textSize="10sp"
                        android:textStyle="normal" />
                </RelativeLayout>
            </com.kdcos.contsync.utilities.dragview.DragLayer>

        </LinearLayout>
```

this is my `xml` i want  keep `rl_dropView` `center` inside `com.kdcos.contsync.utilities.dragview.DragLayer`  i wrote  `xml` like this i am unable to set it please look my screen please look i want to set  `dropView` `center` but from my code its coming top left please suggest how to set it in `center`.

below is my current Screen:

[image]

Comment: What does your `com.kdcos.contsync.utilities.dragview.DragLayer` inherit from? Is it a child of `RelativeLayout`?

Comment: it extend from MyAbsoluteLayout(context, attrs), DragSource, DropTarget @ Abdullah Aftab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if `DragLayer` is SubClass of `RelativeLayout` then it should work otherwise try below solution

**Solution 1**

```
    <com.kdcos.contsync.utilities.dragview.DragLayer
                android:id="@+id/framelayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

           <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/rl_dropView"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:padding="40dp">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imageView"
                        android:layout_width="30dp"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:background="@drawable/ic_drop_cards" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView2"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center"
                        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:lineSpacingExtra="10sp"
                        android:text="Drop Cards Here"
                        android:textColor="@color/blackDark"
                        android:textSize="10sp"
                        android:textStyle="normal" />
                </RelativeLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
            </com.kdcos.contsync.utilities.dragview.DragLayer>
```

**UPDATE**

**Solution 2**

as I can see  `android:orientation="vertical"` in your code under `DragLayer`.its mean `DragLayer` is SubClass of `LinearLayout`, so in your `RelativeLayout` just change

```
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
```

to:

```
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
```

Comment: thanx can you please one more help in another question

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48293198/how-to-drag-and-drop-on-dropped-position-and-delete-item-from-dragview-in-androi  can u help in this if you have worked on this before